# regexp_replace() - matches but does not replace at end of line

Tags: regex, replace, mariadb, pcre

I'm trying to `regexp_replace()` all the values of a column ending without "/", by adding "/".

I can get the correct values by using this statement (the pattern was tested with a PCRE checker):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP("(?<=[^\/])$");
```

And the non-matching ones with:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column` REGEXP("(?<![^\/])$");
```

But when the statement is:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REGEXP_REPLACE(`column`, "(?<=[^\/])$", "/");
```

Then, there is no change, whatever value I put into the third parameter:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1031  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: Have you tried something like `REGEXP_REPLACE(\`column\`, "^(.*[^/])$", "\\1/")` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this easily without regex:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = `column` + '/'
WHERE RIGHT(`column`, 1) <> '/'
```

Comment: I use regexp_replace() quite often, so I was trying to understand why it does not work. Anyway, thanks for the working solution!

Answer (score 0):

> trying to understand why it does not work

As I rationalize the problem, you are asking `REGEXP_REPLACE` to do two things:

- Discover that something is missing, and
- Point to a location in the string.

Your regexp says that it is missing, but I question whether it points to a specific substring (even an empty one) for replacing.  It's easy to point to a *found* substring (or substrings).  It is hard to point to a *missing* substring.  And such a 'pointer' is needed to do the replacement.

Hence, Michal's approach (even if some regexp were needed) is the "right" way to solve the problem.